# Object id of object returned by python function

Tags: python

I am returning a list from a python function, but I am having difficulty in comprehending how the new object (list) creation works in this case.

Running on Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.7.4.
Please check the following code:

```py
def fun():
    return [1, 2, 3]


# CASE 1
x = fun()
y = fun()
print(x is y)  # Results in 'False'

# CASE 2
print(fun() is fun())  # Results in 'False'

# CASE 3
print(id(fun()))  # Prints 140347113376816
print(id(fun()))  # Prints 140347113376816  (SAME !!)
```

I was expecting that even for case 3 I would be getting different IDs when calling fun() twice, similar to case 1 and case 2.

Comment: Why is this closed? I would like to know the reason for CASE 2.

Comment: @Matthias are class objects treated the same as functions?

Comment: @Axois Even in case 2 equality is being tested on objects only, not functions.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW I think i've gotten abit confused over the `id(fun())` and the return object of the `fun()`. For CASE 2 (correct me if i am wrong) `fun() is fun()` returns False because they are pointing to a different space in memory?(since they are technically 'called' at the same time) . I understand CASE 3 through the duplicate. However i am still abit hazy over CASE 2.

Comment: @Axois In "fun() is fun()", first fun() returns an object, and then that object remains in memory because it is still required to be compared for equality, now when second fun() is called it has to return a new object (list) because memory location of first is not yet free, so that's why it results in false. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW okay. Thank you for clearing this up. I have learnt something new :)

Comment: @Axois No problem, I've learned something new too. :)